# Calculate storage value considering inputs and outputs in R

Tags: r, input, output

I'm having difficulty performing a reservoir balance process, I explain.

I want to calculate the value stored at the end of the month considering input and output (consumption).

EX:

At the beginning (beginning of January) the reservoir is empty, so there is an input of X value and an output of Y value. What remains will be the stored value. So in the month of February there is a new input (X may be different from X in January) and the exit remains constant. The stored value will now be February Input + January Stored Value - output. and so on until the month of December.

With the proviso that if the result is negative it will consider 0 and if it is greater than 16000 it will consider 16000

My data is:

| month | input | Exit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jan | 4700 | 2250 |
| fev | 6990 | 2250 |
| mar | 8900 | 2250 |
| abr | 9000 | 2250 |
| may | 5250 | 2250 |
| jun | 2790 | 2250 |
| jul | 1770 | 2250 |
| ago | 492 | 2250 |
| set | 89 | 2250 |
| out | 572 | 2250 |
| nov | 830 | 2250 |
| dez | 744 | 2250 |

expected result:

| month | input | Exit | Stored |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jan | 4700 | 2250 | 2516 |
| fev | 6990 | 2250 | 7256 |
| mar | 8900 | 2250 | 13980 |
| abr | 9000 | 2250 | 16000 |
| may | 5250 | 2250 | 16000 |
| jun | 2790 | 2250 | 15688 |
| jul | 1770 | 2250 | 14677 |
| ago | 492 | 2250 | 12772 |
| set | 89 | 2250 | 10584 |
| out | 572 | 2250 | 8735 |
| nov | 830 | 2250 | 7066 |
| dez | 744 | 2250 | 5915 |

I managed to do it in excel, but I need to automate some things and that's why I'm using R

Comment: How did You get 2516 as Stored in January?

Comment: I have rounded the values... so it may diverge
but, the logic would be.

StoregeJAN = input - output
StorageFEV = Input + storageJAN - output
StorageMar = input + storageFEV - output

Comment: Please DONT ROUND VALUES, it goes against the very core of what we consider a REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE

Comment: Use your actual data instead

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Data Here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IhsxhwMGKO1MNAK1_0SUz5mjwcDDyTPi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please let SO-members know that the solution works by accepting it. If it does not do the job, please let me know. Maybe I can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tidyverse option using `purrr::accumulate` could look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

bound_sum <- function(x, y) {
  
  if (x+y > 16000) 
    16000 
  else if (x+y < 0)
    0
  else
    x+y
}

df %>%
  mutate(diff = case_when(row_number() == 1 & input-exit < 0 ~ 0,
                          row_number() == 1 & input-exit > 16000 ~ 16000,
                          T ~ input-exit),
         stored = accumulate(diff, bound_sum)) %>%
  select(-diff)

# # A tibble: 12 x 4
#    month input  exit stored
#    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1 jan    4700  2250   2450
#  2 fev    6990  2250   7190
#  3 mar    8900  2250  13840
#  4 abr    9000  2250  16000
#  5 may    5250  2250  16000
#  6 jun    2790  2250  16000
#  7 jul    1770  2250  15520
#  8 ago     492  2250  13762
#  9 set      89  2250  11601
# 10 out     572  2250   9923
# 11 nov     830  2250   8503
# 12 dez     744  2250   6997
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(month = c("jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "may", "jun", 
"jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez"), input = c(4700, 6990, 
8900, 9000, 5250, 2790, 1770, 492, 89, 572, 830, 744), exit = c(2250, 
2250, 2250, 2250, 2250, 2250, 2250, 2250, 2250, 2250, 2250, 2250
)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked very well. Now I will go ahead in the application!!

Comment: doing some tests I realized that when the output is greater than the input in the first month it is not getting 0,. what can I add to get around this problem

Comment: @HerminioSabino: I have edited the solution to solve the problem. It now also handles the opposite case where the difference in the first month is greater than 16000.